# difference about threadings in iphone

Tags: iphone

I am working on thread in Iphone. Can anyone explain the difference between

```
[NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(loadButtonInfo:) toTarget:self withObject:buttonInfo];
```

and

```
[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(loadButtonInfo:) withObject:buttonInfo waitUntilDone:NO];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first method creates a new (background) thread and runs the specified method.

The second calls the specified method on the main thread. This is important because the main thread is the only thread in which you should manipulate the user interface. So, if you update the data in your model in a background thread, for example, you might then want to execute a method in the main thread to update the display to reflect the new data.

Comment: Caleb : so for the second one performSelectorOnMainThread, what i am picturing right now is : we are having a main thread, peforSelectorOnMainThread we make a new branch but it is still attached to the main thread....Am I rite at this point.I am confused the last part of your explanation.Is ***performSelectorOnMainThread*** used to get data (from where else) and then i will display or (update) data on the main thread ?

Comment: There's no 'branch' to speak of. At some point after you call that method, the main thread will send the specified message to the receiver. In your example, the main thread will run `[self loadButtonInfo:buttonInfo]`. Did you read [the documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsobject_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSObject/performSelector:onThread:withObject:waitUntilDone:) for -performSelectorOnMainThread:...? The explanation there seems pretty clear.

Comment: i just went over the documentation. Thanks for that. I am still wondering that when should we use *performSelectorOnMainThread* and when  should we use *NSThread detachNewThreadSelector*

Comment: Why are you using either one? Are you making calls to UIKit? Manipulating the user interface? Do that on the main thread. Are you performing some long calculation or loading data over a network connection? You might want to do that on a background thread so you don't tie up the main thread, making the UI feel unresponsive.